How do you Open a terminal on Github to move images?

I am working on assingment where I am using github to add images to a website.  For the most part I understand everything except the last part.  the intructions are

Open a terminal to move the images provided in the /resources folder to the /images folder inside your /rescue directory using the command below:
mv ./resources/* ./rescue/images/
I do not know how to do this.
I tried the options buttion and I clicked the teminal option, and then clicked new terminal.

Check docs for GitHub desktop: https://docs.github.com/en/desktop/overview/launching-github-desktop-from-the-command-line#
or use the OS terminal after you clone the repo
